# My 1-bit ALU is not able to do subtraction

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, verilog, hdl, alu

I am trying to make a 4-bit ALU in Verilog which can perform the following functions:

1. Add
2. Subtract
3. Compare (>,<,=)
4. AND

The approach I have taken is to make 4, 1-bit ALUs and connect them in order to get my 4-bit ALU.

You can see my code for the ALU and its constituent modules at my git repo: https://github.com/KoustubhJain/Verilog

My 1-bit ALU is able to perform all the functions except for subtracting two bits. I have explained how my ALU works and what the files are in more detail in the readme file in the repo.

Basically, I am trying to use the same full adder (carry look ahead type) for subtraction by taking complement of the 2nd input bit and the carry input (called borrow input in case of subtraction). But, it isn't working.

The modules in the ALU, i.e., the adder, the comparator and the decoder work fine by themselves. But, when I connect them as described in the repo, they don't function properly in subtract mode. It works fine in add, compare and bitwise AND mode.

Following is a picture of the circuit I am trying to make as my 1-bit ALU (you can also find it in the repo as `1_bit_ALU.pdf`):

[image]

Comment: Show us your testbench, too.

Comment: @DaveTweed I have added my testbench now (M1=0,M0=0 --> ALU is in subtract mode)

Comment: Why does your and instance have a name (`g1`) but your or instance don't?

Comment: This is just gibberish -- the epitome of "write only" code. It's impossible for someone else to understand this design from the information provided, without spending an inordinate amount of time reverse-engineering it. Even then, we have to guess at what it was intended to do versus what it actually does. If you want our help, make your problem easy to understand.

Comment: @DaveTweed apologies, I am new to SE. I have added a link to my github repo containing all the code and a circuit diagram. I have tried to explain what my circuit is supposed to do in the readme file in the repo. I hope this helps.

Comment: I commend you on your effort to respond to these comments and improve your question.

Comment: I finally figured out why your diagram looks so hideously complex -- you have a whole bunch of AND gates on the input side of your "add", "and" and "compare" functions. There's absolutely no need for this; the inputs of all those functions should connect directly to the A, B and Cin ports of the slice, as appropriate.

Comment: @DaveTweed if A,B,Cin directly connect to my add, and and compare blocks, won't the decoder be useless? And I would be doing every operation instead of doing the operation chosen by the user. I want to design the ALU such that only the operation selected via the decoder is executed.

Comment: Your decoder is already selecting the correct outputs to send to F and Cout. The outputs of the other functions are simply ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you have taken has served you well until now.  You carefully constructed sub-components (adder, decoder, etc.) and proven to yourself that they work individually using Verilog simulations.  You have also connected them up and proven that your design works for some modes of operation (AND, Add, etc.).

However, since you are now having difficulty with how to proceed to fix the problem you have, I strongly recommend you consider a new approach.

Verilog supports designing logic using several levels of abstraction.  You are currently coding at a very low level of abstraction, using "**structural**" modeling with instances of primitive gates (`or`, `and`, etc.).  You are at the point where it has become unwieldy.  As you have discovered, it is very difficult to debug design code at this level, which is why I suggest you re-design your code to use "**behavioral**" modeling.

I think you are ready to take this leap in abstraction.  You have already done the hard work of understanding how to use Verilog to describe basic components like adders.  To overcome the difficulties you are experiencing, you can replace an adder with a single line of behavioral code, such as:

```
sum = a + b;
```

I think providing a detailed review of your Verilog code is beyond the scope of this site.  However, there is another Stack Exchange site dedicated to code reviews.  I recommend you to post your code on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog), but before doing so:

1. Make sure to read the [policy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) first.
2. Only post code that you know is **working**.  Do not post the part of the code that attempts to do subtraction.
3. Post the entire code directly into the question body.  It is not sufficient to simply post a link to your repo.  You can post it all in a single code block (making it easy for others to copy), and post the testbench (making it easy for others to run).

---

If you continue with your approach, you need to painstakingly debug each node of your circuit by looking at waveforms of all the internal nodes.  Make sure each Verilog signal waveform matches the expected node in your schematic drawing.

With so many connections, you should use connection-by-name instead of port order for the module instances you created.  This is a common pitfall in Verilog.  Refer to [How to instantiate a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066850/verilog-how-to-instantiate-a-module)

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to check out CodeReview. But this is a part of a university project where we have been restricted to use only structural modelling. As such, I cannot use behavorial modelling for my project.

Comment: The odd thing is, a statement like `or (F, F0&(t0|t1), F1&t2, F2&t3);` is already using a mix of structural and behavioral modeling. Your university is not doing you any favors by forcing you to do structural modeling beyond the most basic circuits. You would never do that in a real job.

Comment: @KoustubhJain: You're welcome.  I updated my answer with more advice.